# How to connect from ios app to local WIFI and Transfer information/photos

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, ios7

I have not seen anyone ask this,so  i ask about how do I transfer information / images through the WIFI in the iOS app (Xcode).

For example: if I'm flipping through the pictures with a camera that has WIFI How can I go and see the pictures iPhone?

For example like this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJSw48FhXWo

Is there a possibility to access it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at Bonjour?

Comment: Also take a look at Socket connections: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html

Comment: david and simpleBob Thank you, thank you for the help, I think Trapped me some things.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Socket Prgogramming with Bonjour. You can even find the sample code for connecting with the user on same network like wifi.
You need to use CFReadStream, CFWriteStream and NSNetService.
You can check this code as well , see the serverless demon in this.
Here is the link..
[XMPP Sample](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework)

For file transfer protocol just check TurnSocket Extension used in this..
Further XMPP extensions are here on this link:-

[XMPP Extensions](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/xmpp-extensions/)

Comment: @DvirEL Always Welcome